# Visual Basic Else If statement

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I am doing an assignment for an Intro to Business Programming class. It uses visual basic 2017. We have to have a program that keeps track of student grades using a do while loop and else if statements. The professor tasked us with ending the loop by entering -1 into the input box, but it cannot be used in the calculations. This is what I have and it isn't working.

```
Do
    'Prompt user for a score
    strInput = InputBox("Enter test Score")

    If Integer.TryParse(strInput, intTestScore) Then

        If intTestScore >= 0 And intTestScore <= 100 Then

            'Calculate running totals for each letter grade
            If intTestScore >= 93 Then
                'Increase student Count A by  1
                intStudentCountA += 1
                'add intTestScore to current score total A
                intTotalA += intTestScore

            ElseIf intTestScore >= 90 Then
                'Increase student Count A- by 1
                intStudentCountAMinus += 1
                'add intTestScore to current score total A-
                intTotalAMinus += intTestScore

            ElseIf intTestScore >= 87 Then
                'Increase student Count B+ by 1
                intStudentCountBPlus += 1
                'add intTestScore to current score total B+
                intTotalBPlus += intTestScore

            ElseIf intTestScore >= 83 Then
                'Increase student Count B by 1
                intStudentCountB += 1
                'add intTestScore to current score total B
                intTotalB += intTestScore

            ElseIf intTestScore >= 80 Then
                'Increase student Count B- by 1
                intStudentCountBMinus += 1
                'add intTestScore to current score total B-
                intTotalBMinus += intTestScore

            ElseIf intTestScore >= 77 Then
                'Increase student Count C+ by 1
                intStudentCountCPlus += 1
                'add intTestScore to current score total C+
                intTotalCPlus += intTestScore

            ElseIf intTestScore >= 73 Then
                'Increase student Count C by 1
                intStudentCountC += 1
                'add intTestScore to current score total C
                intTotalC += intTestScore

            ElseIf intTestScore >= 70 Then
                'Increase student Count C- by 1
                intStudentCountCMinus += 1
                'add intTestScore to current score total C-
                intTotalCMinus += intTestScore

            ElseIf intTestScore >= 67 Then
                'Increase student Count D+ by 1
                intStudentCountDPlus += 1
                'add intTestScore to current score total D+
                intTotalDPlus += intTestScore

            ElseIf intTestScore >= 63 Then
                'Increase student Count D by 1
                intStudentCountD += 1
                'add intTestScore to current score total D
                intTotalD += intTestScore

            ElseIf intTestScore >= 60 Then
                'Increase student Count D- by 1
                intStudentCountDMinus += 1
                'add intTestScore to current score total D-
                intTotalDMinus += intTestScore

            ElseIf intTestScore >= 0 Then
                'Increase student Count F by 1
                intStudentCountF += 1
                'add intTestScore to current score total F
                intTotalF += intTestScore

            End If

        End If
        'running total
        intTotal += intTestScore
        'increase student counter by 1
        intStudentCount += 1


        'add the score to listbox
        lstScore.Items.Add(intTestScore.ToString())

    Else
        MessageBox.Show("The value must be an integer. The maximum possible score is 100.")

    End If

Loop While intTestScore <> -1
```

I didn't include the variables because this post would be really really long. I'm not sure why -1 is still being calculated. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like your `intTotal += intTestScore` and the following lines are in the wrong place. They should be in the `If /End If` block where the input number has beed validated (between 0 and 100). Otherwise it will count a +[something] and add a score to the List even when the value is -1.

Answer (score 1):

A `Do...While` loop only checks the condition at the end.

It starts an iteration of the Loop, then gets the test score.

```
'Prompt user for a score
strInput = InputBox("Enter test Score")
```

Then it executes the body of the loop, until it gets to the end, where it sees that the score is `-1` and exits the loop.

Another way to write this would be to have the loop run indefinitely.

```
Do
    //Body
Loop While True
```

And then checking if the Score is `-1` and exiting the loop.

```
If intTestScore = -1
    Exit Do
```